# Facebook iOS SDK 3.1 post image on friends wall error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, post

I am using the latest Facebook iOS SDK 3.1.1
while trying to post UIImage on friends wall i`m getting error 5 (Error: HTTP status code: 403).

if i try to post the image on MY wall its working well, but not of one of my friends.

My Code:
1. before posting i am checking if the user has the right permissions, when he does i am making

```
-(void)postImageOnFriendsWall:(UIImage*)image FriendsArray:(NSArray*)friends
{
    // if we don't have permission to announce, let's first address that
    if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound)
    {

    [FBSession.activeSession reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
                                               defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                             completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error)
         {
             // re-call assuming we now have the permission
             [self postImageOnFriendsWall:image FriendsArray:friends];

         }
         else
         {
             UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]  initWithTitle:@"Error"                        message:error.localizedDescription                                                                                                delegate:nil                                                                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alertView show];
         }

     }];
}
else
{

    // can post image
    for (id<FBGraphUser> user in friends)
    {


        NSString *userID = user.id;
        NSLog(@"trying to post image of %@ wall",userID);
        NSMutableDictionary  *postVariablesDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [postVariablesDictionary setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) forKey:@"picture"];
        [postVariablesDictionary setObject:@"my image" forKey:@"message"];

        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos",userID] parameters:postVariablesDictionary HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
         {
             if (error)
             {
                 //showing an alert for failure
                 UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]  initWithTitle:@"Facebook" message:error.localizedDescription                                                                                                delegate:nil   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"              otherButtonTitles:nil];
                 [alertView show];
             }
             else
             {
                 //showing an alert for success
                 UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]  initWithTitle:@"Facebook" message:@"Shared the photo successfully"                                                                                                delegate:nil   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"              otherButtonTitles:nil];
                 [alertView show];
             }
         }];



    }
}
}
```

to mention, if i change

`startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos",userID]`

to

```
startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"me/photos",userID]
```

its working ok.

what am i doing wrong?
i have been trying to look for answers but nothing helped.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you have insufficient permissions level.
As FB docs say:

> Insufficient_scope The request requires higher privileges than
>   provided by the access token. The resource server SHOULD respond with
>   the HTTP 403 (Forbidden) status code and MAY include the "scope"
>   attribute with the scope necessary to access the protected resource.

You must obtain advanced permissions to post to another user's wall. The permission you need is @"publish_stream" which "enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's stream and to the streams of the user's friends. This is a superset publishing permission which also includes publish_actions."(c)

The latest changes force you to divide the permissions needed onto two levels - **basic** which allows you to read basic information about the user and **advanced** (post, etc.)
Here's permissions lists:
[Extended permissions list](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/)

This means that you have to ask for appropriate permissions into two steps. First obtain basic and then ask for advanced.

Comment: Wow!
Thanks man! i cant even say how much i appreciate it! it works great!
saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: Not at all, you should accept the answer if it helped you. Click on the checkmark near the votes count.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your facebook Application id sometimes problem create with it.Cos I have same problem to post wall to my friends wall but change facebook Application id and its work perfect.