# getting error while posting image on user wall using FBDailog in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios4, ios6.1

I was trying to post image on my timeline using FBDialog class.

I'm getting the final url as

https://m.facebook.com/dialog/feed?picture=file%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FUsers%2Fprakash%2FLibrary%2FApplication%2520Support%2FiPhone%2520Simulator%2F6.1%2FApplications%2F19C4DD7D-87C8-4CD7-ABE1-B64AC2D963F2%2FDocuments%2FUploadedImage.jpg&sdk=2&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&app_id=446436425445989&display=touch

But getting following error message:

An error occurred. Please try again later.
API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: picture URL is not properly formatted

```
            UIImage *imge=[UIImage imageNamed:self.proSelectedImage];
            NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imge);
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
            NSString *filePath = [documentsPath            stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UploadedImage.jpg"];
            NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            [fileManager createFileAtPath:filePath contents:pngData attributes:nil];
            NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
            filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wildFlower" ofType:@"jpg"];
            NSLog(@"%@",filePath);
            NSString *file= [url absoluteString];

            FacebookManager *myFacebook = [FacebookManager sharedInstance];
            [myFacebook setDelegate:self];
            NSString *kAppId=[FacebookManager sharedInstance].appID;
            NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                           kAppId, @"app_id",
                                           file ,@"picture",
                                           nil];
          [[[FacebookManager sharedInstance] facebook] dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

this code is working fine if I replace the file path with some static url from google. But its showing the above error message every time I tried to upload form my iPhone gallery.

So I just wanna get the local(iPhone gallery) image url.

Answer (score 0):

In new rule and regulation by Facebook you can't post anything on your friend's wall,although you can tag them to show on their wall. Please find the link which is beneficial for you
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817590/facebook-ios-sdk-3-1-post-image-on-friends-wall-error). 
 Hope this helps